# How to stop entire printf statement from repeating but allow the char value to repeat?

Tags: c

I wish to make simply the char variable that is input by the user to repeat based off of the int variable they input along with it.

For example:
A user input of D10 would output "DO-WHILE: DDDDDDDDDD"

With my current code:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char value;
    int iterations, numIter;

    printf("+----------------------+ \nLoop application STARTED\n+----------------------+\n\n");
    
    printf("D = do/while | W = while | F = for | Q = quit\n");
    printf("Enter loop type and the number of times to iterate (Quit=Q0): ");
    scanf(" %c%d", &value, &iterations);

    for (numIter = 0; numIter < iterations; numIter++)
    {
        if ((value == 'D') && (iterations > 3 || iterations < 20))
        {
            printf("DO-WHILE: %c", value);
```

I did look up answers to this question but nothing seemed to latch on exactly to how I must do it here, I did learn of using the (numIter = 0; numIter < iterations; numIter++) to get numIter(number of iterations) to increase based off what the user input but cannot understand how to make that apply to the letter variable user input for "value".

This causes the entire statement along with the %c value to repeat 10 times if the user input D10. I can kind of understand that it seems wrong but can't tell why or how to fix it.

Comment: An obvious start would be to move the `"printf("DO-WHILE:"` part outside the loop. That is `printf("DO-WHILE:")` before the loop and `printf("%c", value)` inside the loop.

Comment: And you probably don't need the `(value == 'D')` check. Assuming the intention is to print whatever character the user enters and not just `D`.

Comment: @kaylum, I see that makes a lot of sense and kind of embarrassed I didn't notice that possibility. Also i'm very new to C and coding in general but I used the ``` (value == 'D') ``` to only allow it to work if it is that letter, I repeated this as else if statements for the 3 other letter options available so that when its not any of those 4 letters it tells the user they're wrong might not be super efficient though im unsure.

Comment: Think about the conditions trying to limit the range of iterations. `835` is more than `3`, so the condition is satisfied (true) and the printing will fill the screen many times over!! You want `x > 3 && x < 20`; AND, not OR...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use do-while as your code showing ,

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char value;
    int iterations, numIter;

    printf("+----------------------+ \nLoop application STARTED\n+----------------------+\n\n");
    
    printf("D = do/while | W = while | F = for | Q = quit\n");
    printf("Enter loop type and the number of times to iterate (Quit=Q0): ");
    scanf(" %c%d", &value, &iterations);

  
        if ((value == 'D') && (iterations > 3 || iterations < 20))
        { 
            printf("DO-WHILE:"); 
            numIter = 0;
                do{      
                  
                    numIter=numIter+1;
                    printf("%c", value);
                }
                while(numIter < iterations);
                   
                    
                 
          
        }
   
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: Yeah that makes sense as it does get covered in other sections of my college's introduction to C website. I'll have to read through it some more but I think you may be right thanks.